# Reduce size of autoload_static.php for shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel-8, shared-hosting

I have a project,which is on  Laravel 8.14, and will be released to `infinityFree` hosting, but that hosting prevents to upload files which has larger than 1MB.
Which part of `autoload_static.php` can I remove safely in order to reduce the size of the file into 1MB?

Comment: The short answer is to just start removing the modules/library that _you_ know you aren't using. Another option is to just hack `autoload_real.php` and remove the usage of the static version, although at the risk of some performance probably. Or, I guess you could just manually break static into a couple of smaller files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Very simple answer, Remove the extra libraries which you are not using , but are still in the file, this will decrease your file size and then you can upload it without any problem.

Also you can show us the exact file, which will make it easy for people in this community to Analyze the file and help you.

Thanks